# Getting error when tried to update a table using stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, procedure

UPDATE IDConfig SET FemaleID = FemaleID + 1;

Getting Error like You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column
 To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL tool uses this mechanism to tell you that you are about to update ALL records in a table. Normally you have a WHERE clause to limit the data that should be updated.

So to really update ALL records change that option in the configuration or use a WHERE clause to limit your data to update.

You probably can trick your tool with this query

```
UPDATE IDConfig 
SET FemaleID = FemaleID + 1
WHERE 1 = 1
```